# Redirect after login React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i've been trying since days to redirect my user after login to the home creating a callback function in my App.js and sending it as props to the login class component throught a loginregisterpage class component, but this doesn't work, can someone have a look on it and tell me what i;m missing out?
Thank you my code look like this

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { HomePage } from './Pages/HomePage/HomePage'
import { LoginRegisterPage } from './Pages/LoginRegisterPage/LoginRegisterPage'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authenticated: false,
    }
    this.handleSuccess = this.handleSuccess.bind(this);

  }
  handleSuccess = (data) => {
    this.props.history.push("/")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <HomePage />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/login-register">
            <LoginRegisterPage onLoginSuccess={this.handleSuccess} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

LoginRegisterPage class component

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            accessToken: '',
            authenticated: ''
        };
        this.handleChangeUsername = this.handleChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);

    }

    handleChangeUsername(event) {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleChangePassword(event) {
        this.setState({
            password: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        var apiBaseUrl = "https://myapi.com/auth/"
        const payload = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'username': this.state.username,
                'password': this.state.password
            })
        };
        const { username, password } = this.state;

        if (username && password) {
            fetch(apiBaseUrl + 'login', payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        alert("Logged In! You'll be redirected on Home")
                        return response.json()
                    } else {
                        return alert("wrong pass")
                    }
                }).then((data) => {
                    this.setState({
                        accessToken: data.accestToken,
                        authenticated: data.authenticated
                    });
                    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
                    if (data.authenticated === true) {
                        console.log(this.props)
                        this.props.onLoginSuccess(data)
                    }

                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } else {
            alert("Cannot be Empty")
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form">
                    <div>
                        <div className="form-input">
                            <div >
                                <div className="userData">
                                    <span>
                                        <img
                                            src={UserIcon}
                                        />
                                    </span>
                                    <input
                                        autocomplete="off"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="username"
                                        placeholder="Username"
                                        value={this.state.username}
                                        onChange={this.handleChangeUsername}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="userData">
                                    <span>
                                        <img
                                            src={PasswordIcon}
                                        />
                                    </span>
                                    <input
                                        autocomplete="off"
                                        type="password"
                                        name="password"
                                        placeholder="Password"
                                        value={this.state.password}
                                        onChange={this.handleChangePassword}
                                    />
                                    <p style={(this.state.username && this.state.password) ? { display: 'none' } : { display: 'block' }}> Must fill all the form!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-footer">
                    <img
                        src={Btn}
                        onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

LoginPage class component

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            accessToken: '',
            authenticated: ''
        };
        this.handleChangeUsername = this.handleChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);

    }

    handleChangeUsername(event) {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleChangePassword(event) {
        this.setState({
            password: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        var apiBaseUrl = "https://movies-app-siit.herokuapp.com/auth/"
        const payload = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'username': this.state.username,
                'password': this.state.password
            })
        };
        const { username, password } = this.state;

        if (username && password) {
            fetch(apiBaseUrl + 'login', payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        alert("Logged In! You'll be redirected on Home")
                        return response.json()
                    } else {
                        return alert("wrong pass")
                    }
                }).then((data) => {
                    this.setState({
                        accessToken: data.accestToken,
                        authenticated: data.authenticated
                    });
                    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
                    if (data.authenticated === true) {
                        console.log(this.props)
                        this.props.onLoginSuccess(data)
                    }

                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } else {
            alert("Cannot be Empty")
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form">
                    <div>
                        <div className="form-input">
                            <div >
                                <div className="userData">
                                    <span>
                                        <img
                                            src={UserIcon}
                                        />
                                    </span>
                                    <input
                                        autocomplete="off"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="username"
                                        placeholder="Username"
                                        value={this.state.username}
                                        onChange={this.handleChangeUsername}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="userData">
                                    <span>
                                        <img
                                            src={PasswordIcon}
                                        />
                                    </span>
                                    <input
                                        autocomplete="off"
                                        type="password"
                                        name="password"
                                        placeholder="Password"
                                        value={this.state.password}
                                        onChange={this.handleChangePassword}
                                    />
                                    <p style={(this.state.username && this.state.password) ? { display: 'none' } : { display: 'block' }}> Must fill all the form!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-footer">
                    <img
                        src={Btn}
                        onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`App` is defined *outside* the `Router` component so it has no `history` prop function to call to do any navigation.

## Solution

Have the `LoginRegisterPage` component navigate upon successful authentication. It will need to access the `history` object of the nearest `Router` context. Normally this is achieved by consuming passed route props from the `Route` component.

You can:

### #1

Move `LoginRegisterPage` to be rendered by the `component` prop of the `Route` so it receives the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) and thus the `history` object as a prop.

```
<Route exact path="/login-register" component={LoginRegisterPage} />
```

LoginRegisterPage

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        ...
    }

    ...

    handleClick(event) {
        var apiBaseUrl = "https://myapi.com/auth/"
        const payload = {...};
        const { username, password } = this.state;
        const { history } = this.props; // <-- destructure history from props

        if (username && password) {
            fetch(apiBaseUrl + 'login', payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    ...
                }).then((data) => {
                    this.setState({
                        accessToken: data.accestToken,
                        authenticated: data.authenticated
                    });
                    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
                    if (data.authenticated === true) {
                        console.log(this.props)
                        this.props.history.push("/"); // <-- navigate!
                    }

                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } else {
            alert("Cannot be Empty")
        }
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

### #2

Decorate your `LoginRegisterPage` with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component so the route props are injected as props.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom;

...

const LoginPageWithRouter = withRouter(LoginPage);
```

## Note

If you prefer to do a redirect then replace any `history.push` calls with `history.replace`. `push` is a normal navigation and pushes on a new path on the history state whereas `replace` replaces the current history entry in the stack. After the auth redirect you probably don't want users to back navigate back to your login page/route.

## Edit

If you need the `handleSuccess` callback to manage some auth state in `App` then I think it best to let `App` manage the authentication state and the `LoginPage` to still handle navigation. In this case, go with the second solution above so it receives both the `handleSuccess` callback and the `history` object.

```
if (data.authenticated === true) {
  this.props.onLoginSuccess(data); // <-- callback to parent to set state
  this.props.history.replace("/"); // <-- imperative navigation
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried several times importing the router, but didn't worked. Is my real first project in Javascript time consuming i cannot move my component to another path, that was the rules settled to me by my menthor, and as a said also in the other answer above, i need with that redirect function to pass the data from the http request to the app.js where i can set late the `state` of authenticated of the user

Comment: @LiviuCojocaru Then you need to wrap the `Router` around the `App` component so `App` can access the `history` object. Then you can define your auth success callback there where it is and keep your auth state centrally located. Can you include the parent component of `App`? Also, you don't need to move any components to another path, these are ok.

Comment: `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'` my `App.js` is already wrapped in `Router`, i cannot figure out what am i missing

Comment: @LiviuCojocaru Not quite, `App` is wrapping and rendering the `Router`, so by definition it (`App`) is ***not*** wrapped and rendered by the `Router`.

Comment: let me understand so i had to have my `index.js`  like this ```import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css';
import { App } from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
  <Route>
  <App />
  </Route>
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);```

Comment: @LiviuCojocaru Yes, if `index.js` is rendering `App`, then the router should be moved there. `App` can still render the `Switch` and everything else, it just needs to be *inside* a `Router` so it can access the `history` object.

Comment: i did it, it didn't mess all the code but i still get in console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Everything is fine now, i wrapped `App.js` in Router, i sett `loginregisterpage` as component attribute in `<Route exact path="/login-register" component={LoginRegisterPage} />`  and than destructured `{history}` from `props`. How does it work now, does i have to buy you a coffee? Thank you Again

Comment: @LiviuCojocaru That's ok, you missed wrapping the app in a `Router`. Anyway, added an edit to my answer to split the logic of saving the auth state from the logic of redirecting. Just wrap the login component with the HOC to get `history` and call both in the login handler. If answer and explanation were helpful then upvoting is thanks enough. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) you can use the [Redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) component:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function PrivateRoute () {
  if (notLoggedIn()) {
    return <Redirect to="/login"/>;
  }
  // return your component
}
```

But if you're not inside a render function (i.e. you're in a submit callback) or you want to rewrite browser history, use the `useHistory` hook (note: hooks work only in function components, not class components)

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


const history = useHistory();

// After your login action you can redirect with this command:
history.push('/otherRoute');
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your handleSucess function in LoginRegisterPage instead of passing it as a prop and this should work.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that i would like to pass the data from the HTTP to the app.js, where i can access them to all pages, that's why i put me function with data as param, and called back during the http request, If i'm not worng i have to import `{useHistory}` from react to can used the `this.props.history.push('/')` in my login page register class component